# IOS 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'

Tags: ios, objective-c, http-post, nsurlconnection, nsurl

The below code im using to post data to server,it is working fine.but sometimes app going to crash and im getting this error `"'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'".`i checked with internet connection but internet connection is fine no doubt about connection.how to solve this issue.

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myurl.com/test"];

NSString *username   = [_emailLoginString 
stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *password = [_passwordLoginString 
stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableString* requestURL = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:url];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithString:requestURL]]];
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
[request setHTTPBody:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@", 
username,password] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *err;

NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request 
returningResponse:&response error:&err];

NSString *serverRplyLoginString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSDictionary *dictobj=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&err];
  _serverRplyLoginString=[dictobj objectForKey:@"error"];

NSLog(@"Login Response Is :%@",_serverRplyLoginString);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I recommend you to always have an Exception breakpoint enabled:

[image]

[image]

With exception breakpoints it is much easier to fix a crash since the app will pause at the exact line that caused the exception. Now, let's get back to the crash:

Your app crashes because, like the message says, the data parameter is nil. Where? Here:

```
NSDictionary *dictobj=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&err];
```

While you can create an `NSString` with a data parameter of nil:

```
NSString *serverRplyLoginString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

you cannot create an `NSDictionary` using json serialization with a nil data parameter. I recommend you check if the response is nil and handle this situation appropriately.

Oh, and one last thing. I strongly advise you to use async requests over synced because the latter is going to freeze the main queue (i.e. make your app stutter). You could make a simple async request like this:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    if (error || data == nil) {
        // handle the error
    } else {
        // process the response data
    }
}];
```

Comment: what is difference between Asynchronous and synchronous request

Comment: A synchronous operation blocks a process till the operation completes. An asynchronous operation is non-blocking and only initiates the operation. Here: http://www.cs.unc.edu/~dewan/242/s07/notes/ipc/node9.html

Answer (score 0):

> Your code that makes the request:

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myurl.com/test"];

NSString *username   = [_emailLoginString 
stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *password = [_passwordLoginString 
stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableString* requestURL = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:url];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithString:requestURL]]];
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
[request setHTTPBody:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@", 
username,password] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

> Modified for better error handling

```
// declared so that chunk data will be handled
__block NSMutableData *fragmentData = [NSMutableData data];

[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] cancelAllOperations];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
{ 
    //in case your data is chunked 
    [fragmentData appendData:data];

    if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil)
     {
         NSLog(@"No response from server");
     }
     else if (error != nil && error.code == NSURLErrorTimedOut)
     {
         NSLog(@"Request time out");
     }
     else if (error != nil)
     {
         NSLog(@"Unexpected error occur: %@", error.localizedDescription);
     }
     // response of the server without error will be handled here
     else if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil)
     {
         // if all the data was successfully gather without error
         if ([fragmentData length] == [response expectedContentLength])
         {
             // finished loading all your data

             // handle your response data here, in this example it's `fragmentData`

             NSString *serverRplyLoginString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:fragmentData/*responseData*/ encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

             NSDictionary *dictobj=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:fragmentData/*responseData*/ options:kNilOptions error:&err];

             NSLog(@"Login Response Is :%@",serverRplyLoginString);

             NSLog(@"dictobj :%@",dictobj);
         }
         // if fragmentDatas length is not equal to server response's expectedContentLength
         // that means it is a chunked data and the other half of the data will be reloaded and `[fragmentData appendData:data];` will handle that
     }
 }];
```

Comment: Suppose if i post some data to server by using Asynchronous how to get response,bcz i should to show the response to user.in this case is it possible to use Asynchronous.

Comment: under `else if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil)` statement.. 
i logged it already.. NSLog(@"Login Response Is :%@",serverRplyLoginString);

             NSLog(@"dictobj :%@",dictobj);